# What is the use of DataSourceTransactionManager And JndiObjectFactoryBean And JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring

What is the Use of below :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

what is the use of above Classes , I am new to spring, i want to know which purposes we are using above classes

below is my code:-

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
<property name="exceptionMappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="java.lang.Exception">Error</prop>
    </props></property></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 

    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean> 

 <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /></bean>
  <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
  scope="singleton">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/DbDataSource"/>
  <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
  <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/></bean>
  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">      
</bean>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

Spring's using JdbcTemplate class to interact with the database. You would use this class to submit queries. It reduces boilerplate code significantly.

[JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)

---

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager
```

This would be your `TransactionManager`. `TransactionManagers` handle all of your transactional activities - running a query, wrapped in a transaction. As you can see, a `DataSource` is passed to it as a property. `DataSource` would be your `DB` conneciton.

[DataSourceTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.html)

```
org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean
```

---

This is a `Spring` class, that handles your connections to a resource that is acquired by a `JNDI` name.

[JndiObjectFactoryBean](http://javadox.com/org.springframework/spring-context/3.2.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html)

---

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

This line tells your `Spring` container to scan your classes for annotations like `@Transactional`. You use `@Transactional` on a method in your `@Repository` to note that you want it  to be wrapped in the `Transaction`.